# Trying to run python script using terminal and pass inputs in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api, args

I'm trying to pass my input from terminal and run python script, My input is url `http://localhost:8080/api/auth`  and payload is `{ "request":"success","input":[ { "type":" ", "content":[ { "type":" ", "meta":{ "sample_type":" " , deatail":" "} ] } ], "output":[ { "type":" ","content":[ { "type":"", "meta":{  "sample_type":"",  },  "deatils":" " } ] }  ] }`

My Code is here:

```
 def get_response():
        auth_access_Token = get_token()
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A tutorial of argparse!')
        parser.add_argument("--url", action="store_true", required=True )
        parser.add_argument("--payload", action="store_true", required=True )
        a = parser.parse_args()
        url = a.url
        Header = {'Auth': 'Bearer ' + str(auth_access_Token)}
        payload = a.payload

        resp = requests.post(url, headers=Header, json=payload)
        print(json.loads(resp.content))


   get_response()
```

When I pass my inputs using

```
python test.py --url http://localhost:8080/api/auth --payload `{ "request":"success","input":[ { "type":" ", "content":[ { "type":" ", "meta":{ "sample_type":" " , deatail":" "} ] } ], "output":[ { "type":" ","content":[ { "type":"", "meta":{  "sample_type":"",  },  "deatils":" " } ] }  ] }`
```

It's giving me `error: unrecognized arguments`

where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using back ticks for the payload parameter

Comment: Use quotes instead

Comment: If I use  --url "   " --payload " " I'm getting same error

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a couple of problems with your script.

`action` value should be `store` and not `store_true`. 
`store_true` is for `TRUE` and `FALSE` values.

Secondly in order to handle the spaces in the input arguments they must be enclosed in double quotes. As the payload value contains double quotes they must be replace with single quotes.

Here is the modified code

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A tutorial of argparse!')
    parser.add_argument('--url', action="store", nargs=1, type=str, required=True )
    parser.add_argument("--payload", nargs=1, type=str, required=True )
    a = parser.parse_args()
    print(a)
```

So when you invoke the script like this:

```
> python test1.py --url http://localhost:8080/api/auth --payload "{ 'request':'success','input':[ { 'type':' ', 'content':[ { 'type':' ', 'meta':{ 'sample_type':' ' , deatail':' '} ] } ], 'output':[ { 'type':' ','content':[ { 'type':'', 'meta':{  'sample_type':'',  },  'deatils':' ' } ] }  ] }"
```

**EDIT**

You have to process the payload data.
Also I found that the the data you are passing is illformed. 
`"meta":{ "sample_type":" " , deatail":" "}`, see quotes are missing before `deatail` and also some matching braces.

```
payload = a.payload[0]
payload = re.sub(r"'", "\"", payload)
resp = requests.post(url, headers=Header, json=payload)
print(json.loads(resp.content))
```

Comment: After using your change now I'm getting   "raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url) requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for"